# Conditional Formatting - If cell contains a zero?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have column U:

```
0, 0, 2, 1
0, 0, 0, 0
12
1
0
0,2,1
```

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the cell if the cell contains a zero.

```
=SEARCH("substring",U1)="0"
```

This code doesn't seem to be working right, it also highlights cells not containing zero. I'm not sure if the comma is causing the problem?

Please can someone show me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are all the items in the column **Text** or are some of the items **Numbers ??**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent my cells are formatted general but the column only contains numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("0",U1))`. This will look for the character zero, and highlight the cell if this returns TRUE.

Also, if you drag it down to other cells, Excel will change it to $U$1. You should manually remove this anchoring so that it looks at each cell on its own.

Comment: Frielander thanks i've tried this but it causes cells which don't contain zero to also highlight

Comment: Check what I said about the anchoring (dollar signs). You need to edit the conditional formatting.

Comment: Freidlander ok this seems to nearly be working now. I removed the $ signs. However, if the cell contains 100 or 20 etc then this will also be highlighted. I only want to highlight if the number is single digit 0

Comment: Glad it's almost working! This next parameter is a bit trickier. I'd suggest doing `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" 0",U1)), U1=0)`. This searches for either a) 0 by itself or b) a 0 followed by a space. If your commas aren't followed by spaces, you could do a comma instead of a space. If you have numbers that start with 0 but aren't zero, we'll have to tweak it some more.